# Is there a name for using a web site email feature to harass someone or the site?

Tags: email

The scenario is that a website has a password recovery feature: you enter your email and if you have an account with that email, it sends you a recovery link.

But then someone writes a script that requests a recovery every 5 seconds all day long and gives someone else's email to:

- harass that person
- waste site resources sending emails
- get the site blacklisted as a spammer
- other unpleasant consequences

To be clear, the attacker doesn't compromise the site, but just causes grief of different kinds via that site emailer channel. Does this have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the attack that you described is known as *"Password reset email spamming"*, *"Password reset email bombing"* or just simply *"email flooding"*.

Taking the definition from [Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/1655/email-bomb):

Email Bomb:

> An email bomb is a form of Internet abuse which is perpetrated through
>   the sending of massive volumes of email to a specific email address
>   with the goal of overflowing the mailbox and overwhelming the mail
>   server hosting the address, making it into some form of denial of
>   service attack.
>
> An email bomb is also known as a letter bomb.

Also the definition from Cloudmark Security Blog says:

> DDoS attacks are not limited to websites. We are currently seeing some
>   email inboxes being attacked by being inundated by blog forum sign up
>   confirmation and password reset emails. A DDoS attack on an inbox is
>   known as mail bombing, and it is a technique sometimes used by cyber
>   criminals to cover up a more serious attack.

I also include two links where both terms mentioned before are used in a similar attack to the one you described, these attacks were reported on [www.hackerone.com](https://www.hackerone.com) as part of a bug bounty:

- [password reset email spamming](https://hackerone.com/reports/224095)
- [The email API to reset password is unlimited and can be used as a email bomb](https://hackerone.com/reports/222080)

If you want to read more about this attack, I include some extra links:

- [Cloudmark Security Blog](https://blog.cloudmark.com/2017/02/22/mail-bombing-and-what-to-do-about-it/)
- [The Return of Email Flooding](https://www.darkreading.com/endpoint/the-return-of-email-flooding-/a/d-id/1333351)
- [If you start suddenly getting email/spam "bombed" there's probably a reason](https://www.reddit.com/r/personalfinance/comments/bg2my9/if_you_start_suddenly_getting_emailspam_bombed/)
- [How Email Bombing Uses Spam to Hide an Attack](https://www.howtogeek.com/412316/how-email-bombing-uses-spam-to-hide-an-attack/)
- [OWASP Periodic Table of Vulnerabilities - Insufficient Password Recovery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Insufficient_Password_Recovery)
- [mail bomb](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/mail-bomb)
- [Reset password - should I prevent abusing it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24280/reset-password-should-i-prevent-abusing-it)